# Toggle Two Sides Within One Model

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails-4, toggle

I currently have a Location model in place that allows my customer to upload their pertaining locations in the DB. Currently, the setup forces the customer to create two different records if their location has a north and south face.

I am wondering if it is possible to achieve a task that allows my customer to create a single entry for a location and within that, also create records for north and south faces that can be toggled within that record.

Here is a diagram for a better example:

[location toggle http://adsemble.com/images/location-toggle-framework.jpg](http://adsemble.com/images/location-toggle-framework.jpg)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can automatically create two records when the customer enters data for the location.  Just create the data for the records and save the records.

You can also implement a has_one/belongs_to relationship between location and each face, north and south.  i.e. location has_one :north_face, has_one :south_face.  north_face belongs_to :location, south_face belongs_to :location.

Comment: With your method, am I being correct when I state I have to create a North and South face controller/model then?

Comment: yes, you would need to create separate models and controllers.  but that shouldn't make your code too much slower or more complex to write

Comment: Interesting approach. Each location and its face has specific data and a photo that pertains to it. And then each face also has some data that will differ among the two sides. So would this be achieved by bringing the form inputs from north and south face controllers into the location new and somehow setting it so that when the clients hits save, it will save the location data along with the two sides data (if applicable)

Comment: yes, I think that would work.  Thanks for clarifying your problem a bit more.

Comment: Do you know if it is possible to to create these controllers and fields and then make sure the same field names are added to the location model as well and instead of bring in the form from the two models, on save, passing the data entered in the fields to the appropriate model? Or is it easier to go with the process I mentioned above?

Comment: it's not a big deal to bring in the other models where the user would be saving.

Comment: Last question..if I bring in the other models form fields, as long as those are placed within the same location form placement, once the location is saved, it will save those records as well? (one submit)

Comment: Thank you very much for the directional advice. +1 for the guidance